# can't load json data into a grid extjs

Tags: javascript, json, grid, extjs4, store

I tryed every answer i found (in Stackoverflow there are many) to solve my problem with the store of extjs, but still the data doesn't get displayed in the grid, even if the grid is correctly fisplayed. I'm confused so I'm writing the "store" I was able to build reading the answer on this site. I don't know why it's not loading the data into the grid. If you need more information to help please ask.

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'StoreName',
    fields: ['id','name'],
    data : JsonObject,
    model: 'ModelName',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
        type: 'json',
        record: 'JsonRoot'
    }
}
```

})

The grid is loaded in a new window through an ajax call. The code of the new window is the following:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                    title: 'GridTitle',
                    height: 200,
        width: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        items: {  
        xtype: 'grid',
                    border: false,
        columns: [
                    {
            text     : 'id',
                            flex     : 1,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
                text     : 'name',
            width    : 300,
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }],
```

I do have the impression that the part with the columns is not read by ext.js, cause it doesn't index the name and id of the data i'm passing to it in the json.

Comment: You are bringing data in form of Json. Why not try using -type:"ajax" and provide the store with URL

Comment: Cause the grid in already into an Ajax call and the json is the responsetext for this call. So i don't need to make an other call to have the json, it's already there, and can be used as "memory". It doesn't trow any exception, so i assume it is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was so simple that I'm embarrassed to say it.

```
reader: {
         type: 'json',
     root: 'jsonRoot'
        }
```

Instead of:

```
reader: {
         type: 'json',
     record: 'jsonRoot'
        }
```